# Can delegates change parameters in delegate chain? (C#)

Tags: c#, events

We have 1 event, 2 subscribers. When event rises 1st subsriber (function) change parameter and this parameter is of reference type. Will the second subscriber get changed parameter or the origin one?

Comment: Can you add a code example to show what you mean? I suspect from what you've said the answer is they get the changed parameter, but a code example would makes the question clearer.

Comment: Note that there's nothing event-specific here - it may be better to phrase your question solely in terms of delegates, to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't change the parameter to have a different value assuming it's a by-value parameter, but (as always) you may be able to modify the object that the value refers to.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action<StringBuilder> action1 = sb =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
            sb = new StringBuilder("x");
        };
        Action<StringBuilder> action2 = sb =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
            sb.Append("y");
        };
        Action<StringBuilder> action3 = sb =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
            sb.Append("z");
        };

        Action<StringBuilder> all = action1 + action2 + action3;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("a");
        all(builder);
        Console.WriteLine(builder);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a
a
ay
ayz
```

In other words:

- The first action changes the value of its parameter; this doesn't affect anything else
- The second action appends "y" to the `StringBuilder` object its parameter refers to
- The third action can "see" the change made by the second action, and it appends "z"
- After the delegates have been invoked, their changes are visible to the caller

This is all exactly the same as regular method calls passing the parameter by value.

Now you *can* declare a delegate to use `ref` parameters - at which point it behaves like a method with a `ref` parameter, and changes to the parameter itself *are* visible to later delegates in the chain. Here's a version of the above example using a new `RefAction<T>` delegate:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

delegate void RefAction<T>(ref T arg);

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RefAction<StringBuilder> action1 = (ref StringBuilder sb) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
            sb = new StringBuilder("x");
        };
        RefAction<StringBuilder> action2 = (ref StringBuilder sb) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
            sb.Append("y");
        };
        RefAction<StringBuilder> action3 = (ref StringBuilder sb) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
            sb.Append("z");
        };

        RefAction<StringBuilder> all = action1 + action2 + action3;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("a");
        all(ref builder);
        Console.WriteLine(builder);
    }
}
```

Now the output is:

```
a
x
xy
xyz
```

... which shows that the change to the value of `sb` in `action1` *is* visible everywhere else.